# Can I run a renting business in USA as a foreign citizen?

Tags: united-states, non-resident, rental-property, property-taxes, landlord

I'm considering buying a property in Houston, TX for the purpose of renting it. I'm a foreign citizen and don't know much about how renting functions in the USA. So far I found out that it's possible for me to buy a real estate, but I couldn't find anything about renting it. I have several questions:

1. Am I allowed to rent out my property if I'm a foreign citizen?
2. If yes, do I need to register as a business? What are other major pre-requirements?
3. How can I calculate taxes and other business expenses?
4. Are there any other advices that are good to know in advance?

Comment: Out-of-country landlords are not uncommon for commercial property.  (Japanese, Saudis, British, Chinese all own a lot of US property.)  You'll definitely need to speak to an American real estate attorney.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the advice, it means a lot! So a real estate attorney is the address for all my questions? Neat.

Comment: What is your status though ? In the current political climate I would be very weary of doing anything of this sort with any status less than permanent resident. If your visa doesn't get renewed for any reason you're going to have to try to sell property in the US without being in the country. Which, while not impossible, makes things more complicated.
If you are a permanent resident I don't think there are any laws preventing you from doing anything that a US citizen could do (except for political stuff).